# Spouse visa for Ireland

Tags: eu-spouses

My wife is a Bangladeshi citizen, I am Indian. She is staying here on a spouse visa (extended from her tourist visa to a 1-year spouse visa). Now I am moving to Ireland in October for 4 years, with a monthly salary of 2,000 euros (PhD. position). Can she get a dependent visa?